# Replace \tabularnewline with \hline?

Tags: tables, longtable

If I've the following code that is autogenerated (adapted here for sharing) from another tool, that I cannot modify,:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.29\columnwidth} Value\strut \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\columnwidth} Description\strut \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.29\columnwidth} \textbf{Value 1}\strut \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\columnwidth} Some details for 1\strut \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.29\columnwidth} \textbf{Value 2}\strut \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\columnwidth} Some details for 2\strut \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way that I can easily replace `\tabularnewline` with `\hline` in the latex preamble somehow?

I've tried things like this, but with no success. Relax seems to work, but the switch to hline does not.

```
\let\toprule\hline
\let\midrule\hline
\let\bottomrule\relax
\let\tabularnewline\hline
```

I'm basically trying to get horizontal lines at the top, bottom and after every row, so that it ends up looking like this (done using manual search and replace as a proof of concept):

[image: Aim]

Is this possible?

Comment: First of all always post a full minimal example that others  can copy ans test as is. People are more likely to help if they have code they can work with (without having to add anything). Note that you cannot just change `\tabularnewline` to `\hline` as that is not what dis macro does. You might be able to redefine it in to something silimar to ``\\\hline``. Note that I would still use `\toprule` and friends as they have better spacing than `\hline`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks daleif, I appreciate the constructive comments on the posting. I'll make some tweaks to it now for clarity

Comment: All minipages in your table are superfluous ( they are just clutter). The very same result you can get with with properly selected column specifiers.  For other suggestion see my answer.

Comment: I don't have control over the LaTeX, which is why I was trying to see if there was a simple overloading of command that could be used. The flow is Source1->LaTeX->PDF. I am only able to change Source1 or add macros/commands into LaTeX, not re-write LaTeX

Comment: There's always the regex search-and-replace. Either [in Lua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631590/250119) or by [scanning the rest of the file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638830/250119) (the latter might be very slow though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tabular` environment defines `tabularnewline` to some appropriate value when the environment starts, so if you try to define it beforehand it will get overridden when the environment starts anyway.

This is doing literally what the OP asks for (without regarding whether it's a good idea or not), replacing each `tabularnewline` with `\\ \hline`. (note that then the middle rule and the bottomrule get duplicated. It's the readers's exercise to handle them.)

Remark

- `\__a` violates expl3's naming style. Fix yourself if you want.
- Documentation can be found in `texdoc interface3` / `texdoc xparse`
- Synctex is lost, and verbatim cannot be used inside the environment. These can be fixed, but it's a bit difficult.
- For simplicity, the environment grabs the initial `om` arguments inside the `#1`. It doesn't really matter in this case, but watch out if you modify the code.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% ======== backup the old environment
\let    \oldlongtable    \longtable
\let \endoldlongtable \endlongtable


% ======== override it
\RenewDocumentEnvironment {longtable} {+b} {
  \tl_set:Nn \__a {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {\c{tabularnewline}} {\c{ \\ }\c{hline}} \__a
  \exp_args:NV \__printtable:n \__a
}{}

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__printtable:n #1 {
  \begin{oldlongtable} #1 \end{oldlongtable}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.29\columnwidth} Value\strut \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\columnwidth} Description\strut \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.29\columnwidth} \textbf{Value 1}\strut \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\columnwidth} Some details for 1\strut \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.29\columnwidth} \textbf{Value 2}\strut \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\columnwidth} Some details for 2\strut \end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

I would not experimenting what you try to do. Better and far more simple is use `tabularray` package. Using it your code will become very short and clear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}



\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = Table title
                ]{hline{1,Z}=0.8pt, hline{2}=0.4pt, hline{3-Z}=solid,
                 colspec = {@{} X[0.3,l, font=\bfseries]X[0.7,c] @{}},
                 row{1}={font=\bfseries},
                 rowhead=1
                 }
Value   &   Description             \\
Value 1 &   Some details for 1      \\
Value 2 &   Some details for 2      \\
Value 3 &   Some details for 3      \\
Value 4 &   Some details for 4      \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would not draw lines after each row. Also is not clear, if texts   in the second column cells have only one line. Ih have more, than centering it may not be the best choice. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = Table title
                ]{hline{1,Z}=0.8pt, hline{2}=0.4pt, 
                 colspec = {@{} X[0.3,l, font=\bfseries]X[0.7,j] @{}},
                 row{1}={font=\bfseries},
                 row{2-Y}={rowsep=3pt},
                 rowhead=1
                 }
Value   &   Description     \\
Value 1 &   \lipsum[1]     \\
Value 2 &   \lipsum[2]     \\
Value 3 &   \lipsum[11]     \\
Value 4 &   \lipsum[66]     \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

looks nice regardless that text in the second column is not centered.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko, I agree that the output and likewise the source here look good. The background here is that there are certain tables that absolutely do require horizontal lines in order to make the content clearer. Note that the LaTeX above is autogenerated and that part I'm unable to change unfortunately as it's in the middle of a flow that doesn't support processing in the middle

Comment: @BRH, I show you how to simple draw horizontal lines in table (first example) . BTW, So you can use both suggestion. BTW, I strongly disagree with you about horizontal lines. You may look  https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: I cannot change the source though. All I can do is put some LaTeX macros in place. Agree as well on your link absolutely - for a very specific table lines are needed. There was feedback saying they were confusing without